# Is there a way I can find all four variables?

Tags: equation-solving

I need to find a,b,c,d but `solve` or `solveAlways` isn't working.
The code I tried was: `SolveAlways[2 b Log[-1 + (3 (x - c))/a] - 4 b + d == Log[x], {a, b, c, d}]`
The output I got was: `{{Log[-1 + (3 (-c + x))/a] -> -1}, {}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call to `SolveAlways` asks Mathematica to find values for `x` such that the equation holds for all possible values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` which does not help with the question.

To solve for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in terms of `x` you can ask for the most generic solution with

```
eqn = -4*b + d + 2*b*Log[-1 + (3*(-c + x))/a] == Log[x]
Reduce[eqn, {a,b,c,d}]
```

which is only able to give a condition on `d` that is not too helpful

```
d == 4*b + Log[x] - 2*b*Log[-1 + (3*(-c + x))/a]
```

The inability of `Reduce` to find solutions comes from the fact that by default it assumes all variables to be complex. If we restrict all variables to the reals

```
Reduce[eqn, {a,b,c,d}, Reals]
```

we get

```
  ((x > 0 && a < 0 && c > (-a + 3*x)/3) 
|| (x > 0 && a > 0 && c < (-a + 3*x)/3))
&& d == 4*b + Log[x] - 2*b*Log[-1 + (3*(-c + x))/a]
```

This means there are two cases that yield real solutions. Either the thre variables `a`, `c` and `x` satisfy

```
(x > 0 && a < 0 && c > (-a + 3*x)/3)
```

or they satisfy

```
(x > 0 && a > 0 && c < (-a + 3*x)/3)
```

In both cases, the remaining variables `d` and `x` have then the following relation:

```
d == 4*b + Log[x] - 2*b*Log[-1 + (3*(-c + x))/a]
```

For given `a`, `c` and `x` this is a line <strike>through the origin</strike> in the plane. We therefore have infinitely many solutions in the reals even if we fix `a`, `c` and `x`. If you want to find particular solutions, you can use `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[eqn, {a,b,c,d,x}, Reals]

{{a -> 10180463/7817650,
  b -> 1707599/480297768,
  c -> 31579484/44042967, 
  d -> 24304835/123489551, 
  x -> Root[{2707518866729021/14827938929155542 + (1707599*Log[-1 + (23452950*(-31579484/44042967 + #1))/10180463])/240148884 - Log[#1] & , 1.17627114050737935357915375789161771536`15.15051499783199}]
}}
```

Comment: plus 1 for time spend to answer this question

Answer (score 5):

Up to the documentation, "`SolveAlways` works primarily with linear and polynomial equations".
In view of it, we will work with the quantifier `ForAll` instead of `SolveAlways`.
We consider the identity over the positive reals at the beginning. If two expressions are equal,
then  their derivatives are equal too:

```
ForAll[x, x > 0, D[2 b Log[-1 + (3 (x - c))/a] - 4 b + d, x] == D[Log[x], x]];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `b == 1/2 && a + 3 c == 0`

Next, we substitute the above in the LHS of the identity

```
2 b Log[-1 + (3 (x - c))/a] - 4 b + d /. {b -> 1/2, a -> -3 c}
```

> `-2 + d + Log[-1 - (-c + x)/c]`

and use `ForAll` again

```
ForAll[x, x > 0, -2 + d + Log[-1 - (-c + x)/c] == Log[x]];Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `c < 0 && d == 2 - Log[-(1/c)]`

At last, if two analytic functions are equal on on the positive ray of the complex plane,
then these functions coinside on their domain over the complexes, i.e. `x != 0` in the case under consideration.